# How to resolve "no implicit conversion of Class into String" in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typeerror

I have a method in patch as below:

```
def applicable_resource_type(resource_type)
  if resource_type.include?('Student')
    student_setting
  else
    teacher_setting
  end
end
```

This method is called in another patch which checks whether the resource type is 'teacher' or 'student' and stores the boolean value in 'active'.

```
def exams
  School.new(resource: self).request if can_examine_students?
end

private

def can_examine_students?
  active = applicable_resource_type(self.class.name).is_active?
  if active && (self.is_a?(Teacher))
      active = belongs_to_school?
  end
  active
end
```

However the `resource_type` is passed as a `String` whereas in `can_examine_students?` it is passed as a class/module. Is there any way to  make them both consistent?

I tried the following:

```
def applicable_resource_type(resource_type)
  if resource_type.include?(Student)
    student_setting
  else
    teacher_setting
  end
end
```

But it gave error as:

```
TypeError:
  no implicit conversion of Class into String
```

I also tried

```
resource_type.include?('Student'.constantize)
```

But it gave error same `typerror`.

Is there a way to resolve the above error and  keep both consistent resource_type consistent?

Thanks

Comment: Actually, in the second code snippet, when you call `applicable_resource_type(self.class.name)` you also hand over a String `...class.name` is a string. What is the error, when you leave the very first snippet with the string and the second with `self.class.name`? What is self in this context?

Comment: I dont get any error when I leave the very first snippet with the string and the second with self.class.name. But in if part I have passed it as class/module but I want it consistent with patch method. The self here could be `Student` or `Teacher`

Comment: In the second you pass 'object.class.name' - if you try it out in erb with the String class for example, you will see, that it returns a string with the name of the class. So it is a string too. So this is consistent. If you want to write the first method more elegant, you can use `type_of?` I provide an answer below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in the second code snippet, when you call `applicable_resource_type(self.class.name)` you also hand over a String, because `class.name` returns a string.

If you want to write the first method more elegantly, you can use `is_a?` which accepts a class name as an argument. It would look like this:

```
def applicable_resource_type(resource_type)
  if resource_type.is_a?(Student)
    ...
```

Note, that you pass `Student` as a class name.
You then have to adapt the second code snippet too and just pass the class and not `class.name`. Hence,

```
def can_examine_students?
  active = applicable_resource_type(self.class).is_active?
...
```